# Merge two git respositories, keeping all commit history

Tags: git

I have two git repos, each containing different versions of the same code base.

Commits in Repo 1 (most recent last):

```
 version 1
 version 2
 version 3
 version 4
 version 5
```

Commits in Repo 2:

```
 version 3
 commit that isn't a new version
 another commit that isn't a new version
 yet another commit that isn't a new version
 version 5
```

Note that in Repo 1, version 5 is based on version 4, but in Repo 2, version 4 isn't present, as version 5 was really based on version 3 (and version 4 became an abandoned branch, essentially).

I'd like to put all of this into one repo:

```
 version 1
 version 2
 version 3
   branch  version 4
 commit that isn't a new version
 another commit that isn't a new version
 yet another commit that isn't a new version
 version 5
```

I'd appreciate if someone could explain not only *how* to do this, but *why* it's correct to do it that way, so I can gain a better understanding of git.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `git rebase --preserve-merges --onto`. After you fetch the commits of the second repo into the first, you can move parts of history to have the ancestor you want.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

To get changes from the second repo, add it as a remote:

```
git remote add secondary <url to your secondary repo>
```

Then you can fetch from there:

```
git fetch secondary
```

Now you can inspect with `gitk --all` or `git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline` and do what you like with the `rebase --onto`.

Comment: You should probably include how to fetch the commits from the second repo into the first; that would make this an awesome answer.